# SIMPLE XML, empty value parsing description

Tags: android, xml, rss

I'm creating a RSS app on Android based in this tutorial http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/05/tutorial-para-crear-un-lector-rss-en-android/

I deleted some tags that I didn't want to parse and everything runs OK with the original URL, the forbes RSS "http://www.forbes.com/most-popular/feed". Once I change the forbes RSS url for this one I want to use "http://aplicaciones.esi.us.es/antalumnos/rss.xml" I get this error:

```
06-20 13:51:44.961 11441-11494/com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion W/System.err: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Empty value for @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=description, required=true, type=void) on field 'descripcion' private java.lang.String com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion.RssParse.Item.descripcion in class com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion.RssParse.Item at line 11
06-20 13:51:44.971 11441-11494/com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:580)
06-20 13:51:44.971 11441-11494/com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
06-20 13:51:44.971 11441-11494/com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
06-20 13:51:44.971 11441-11494/com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
06-20 13:51:44.971 11441-11494/com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
06-20 13:51:44.971 11441-11494/com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
06-20 13:51:44.971 11441-11494/com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
06-20 13:51:44.971 11441-11494/com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
06-20 13:51:44.971 11441-11494/com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
06-20 13:51:44.971 11441-11494/com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeInlineList.read(CompositeInlineList.java:190)
```

The first line says "empty value for description" but I don't understand why.This is my code for Item Class, there are 2 files more por RSS and Channel:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Namespace;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

/**
 * Clase que representa la etiqueta <item> del feed
 */

@Root(name = "item", strict = false)
public class Item {

    @Element(name="title")
    private String title;

    @Element(name="description", required=false)
    private String descripcion;

    @Element(name="link")
    private String link;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String title, String descripcion, String link) {
        this.title = title;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.link = link;
        ;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
}
```

Is there any problem with the URL that I want to use?

Comment: The first line of the stack trace shows "bla bla bla **at line 11**". So if you check the URL content, on line 11 there is a Description tag without a value, i.e. it is empty. So No, there is no problem with the URL you are using. But I guess you have another question (that is not mentioned): How to handle empty tags using Simple XML framework?

Comment: I thought that required=false was enough in empty cases. Thanks you, I'll check solutions for that case

Comment: required=false is used only to mark the element (or attribute) as not mandatory to be present. But in this case it is present, however it is empty, which apparently is an issue for the framework. I think one way would be to use custom deserialization and you can see an example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25962865/2160877

Answer (score 1):

Move the description element in a new class.
In order to do that, you need to replace

```
@Element(name="description", required=false)
private String descripcion;
```

with

```
@Element(name="description", required=false)
private Description descripcion;
```

Then, create a new file Description.java like:

```
public class Description
{
    @Text(required=false)
    String descriptionText;

    public String getText()
    {
        return descriptionText;
    }
}
```

In this case, whenever description tag is empty, it will be skipped during deserialization, and your `descripcion` field will be simply null.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did it, but same problem again 

"org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Empty value for @org.simpleframework.xml.Text(data=false, empty=, required=true) on field 'descriptionText' public java.lang.String com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion.RssParse.Description.descriptionText in class com.herprogramacin.hermosaprogramacion.RssParse.Description at line 129"

Comment: Hmm, this works on my side with a similar usecase. I made a small edit to the answer. Try again.

Comment: Now is working thank to that required = false !!!! Thanks you very much, really. 

My problem now is other. I was getting description as String but now is an Description object. How should I parse it to string? . If I use description.toString() i get the identifier of the objet. :(

Comment: Use a getter, similar to my updated answer. Then, you will call `description.getText()`

Comment: If this answers your question, then please Accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct, but the problem may lie with the Channel class.  channel too has a description. The error shown in your question mentions description is required (in the Item class it is optional.  May be you Channel class is missing:    @Element(name="description", required=false)?

Comment: I'm using @Root(name = "channel", strict = false). When strict false the parsing will ignore the elements that are not declarated. Forbes RSS has a description within channel and it works in my current code. Thanks